# Wix Setup won't build on VSTS

Tags: wix, azure-devops, wix3.11

Setup project builds locally in VS 2017, won't build in VSTS

> Creating directory "bin\Release\net471\".   Creating directory
>   "obj\Release\net471\".
>   **Error HEAT5053: The directory '...\bin\Release' did not contain any files or sub-directories and since empty directories are not being
>   kept, there was nothing to harvest.**   heat.exe : error HEAT5053: The
>   directory '...\bin\Release' did not contain any files or
>   sub-directories and since empty directories are not being kept, there
>   was nothing to harvest. Done Building Project "...\project.wixproj"
>   (default targets) -- FAILED.

Note, I intentionally truncated the paths above.

We are using the Hosted VS 2017 build agent, and Wix 3.11 is installed on VSTS.

Comment: Please check if this thread helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28749542/wix-heat-error-on-jenkins-ci

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT thanks. I was already going to bin\Release. I added the trailing slash but that didn't make any difference. Same error from Heat, HEAT5053. Thanks.

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT Also, adding AfterResolveReferences Target to Wix Project didn't resolve this error either unfortunately.

Comment: So, just check the build logs to confirm if the output path is correct or not , also check if any other build errors existing there, seems no files outputted. Besides, you can try to deploy a private agent to check if that works for you.